# Grails Database Migrate persistent_logins table not creating

Tags: mysql, grails, spring-security, database-migration

Im facing weird problem. After running s2-create-persistence-token and dbm-create-gorm-changelog and dbm-update and dbm-changelog-sync, my application DID NOT create persistent_logins table for PersisntentLogin table just what is going on here Oo ?

The first script was supposed to create table in database. Then if it was no created dbm-update should force creation with changelog, but its not doing it ?

Any idea what the hell is broken again in this grails scripts >< ?

Comment: Is the table creation statement in the changelog?

Comment: Its fixed. Problem was fact that you are not able to revert sync with db :S